# Correct behavior of pipe operator in linux

Tags: linux, bash

As the pipe operator is unidirectional and takes output from one command and uses it as input for another. I typed

```
sleep 5 | echo "Hello World"
```

I expected the sleep process to complete first and then print "Hello World", but actually the opposite happens where Hello World is printed and then sleep command is executed.

Can some one explain why this happens?

Comment: Did you mean `sleep 5 && echo ...`?

Comment: `echo` isn't waiting for any input, so it doesn't matter whether you use the `|` operator or not.

Comment: @larsks It does matter, since pipes are asynchronous. The OP wants `&&` or `;` to ensure `echo` runs *after* (if at all) `sleep` completes.

Comment: My point is that `echo` is running immediately because it's not looking for input, so the use of the pip operator in this case is a no-op. In other words, the pipe doesn't matter as far as `echo` is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe operator runs both processes concurrently. If the second process needs to read input, it will wait for the first process to write something to the pipe.

But `echo` doesn't read input, so it doesn't wait.

If you instead wrote

```
sleep 5 | { read _; echo "Hello World"; }
```

the output would be delayed because `read` waits for something to be available in the pipe (in this case it will just read EOF because `sleep` doesn't write anything to stdout).